# Очистка истории состояния при перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, history, location

При внутренних изменениях скрипта, вынужден добавлять в юрл динамически значения для get-запросов.

Делаю я это так:    `history.pushState("", "", "?id=" + user.user_id);`

Но проблема в том, что при перезагрузке страницы (F5, ctrl+shift+r), строка всё равно имеет вид типа такой: `www.example.com/?id=1234567`.

Как сделать так, чтобы конкретно при перезагрузке, состояние обнулялось?

То есть я знаю как установить это, `history.pushState("", "", "/");`

Но как отследить факт перезагрузки, не знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: может такой вариант подойдет: `window.onload = function() {
    history.pushState("", "", "/");
   };` ?

Comment: или такой - `window.onbeforeunload = function() { history.pushState("", "", "/"); };`

Comment: @Darth нет и нет. С первым и так ясно, что мне не нужно обнулять при загрузке состояние. Потому что если была добавлена закладка и затем сделан переход, то состояние обнулится. Чего не хотелось бы.

Comment: @Darth а второй триггирится лишь при закрытии окна, а не при перезагрузке.

Comment: 'HTML5 History API' не работает на всех браузерах

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Да нет, во всех работает: http://joxi.ru/YmEp8dKF0vJwpr

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение в таком коде:

`var currentState = history.state;`

Так мы узнаем текущее состояние, если оно было добавлено в текущем сеансе на странице.

А если оно было добавлено, мы можем сверить при перезагрузке странице, и очистить его уже объявленной мною выше строчкой:
`history.pushState("", "", "/");`

Изменяем код добавления состояния на такой:
    `history.pushState({pushed: true}, "", "?id=" + user.user_id);`.

Дальше сверяем:
`if (currentState ? currentState.pushed : false) history.pushState("", "", "/");`

Всё.

Comment: нам что птичку поставить на ваш ответ?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan я ж ставлю птичку. Через дня два и поставлю, в чем проблема? (:

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan совершенно случайно наткнулся на это свойство на сайте мозилы. Там с history api всё не очень круто рассортировано, поэтому я сразу не нашел это свойство.

Comment: вы сами на свой вопрос ответ пишете, проблема в этом.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan я удивлю: но можно писать ответы на свои же вопросы, если до этого никто не дал на них ответ или ответ отличается альтернативным решением)

Comment: это вообще то не моя проблема, но вы подумаете зачем люди здесь вопросы задают, и все. пока.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan сам я ответ написал лишь затем, что кому-то это может быть полезно) В чем ещё могут быть проблемы тут?

Comment: @VostokSisters тут это, два дня, как бы помягче сказать, уже наступили)

Answer (score 0):

Нажмите F12.
вставьте в консоль -

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => localStorage.test = 1;
console.log(localStorage.test) // undefined
```

перезагрузите страницу. повторите.

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => localStorage.test = 1;
console.log(localStorage.test) // 1
```

Comment: Всё-таки мой код более лаконичный)  Конечно, через локал сторедж можно запоминать информацию при переходе. Но слишком уж много нюансов ненужных продумывать (в моей задаче), так что лучше обойтись api history.

Comment: К тому же повторюсь: это закрытие страницы. А не перезагрузка. Код вообще не рабочий в моей задаче и не ответ на вопрос.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/nAy6BDnhY4jgnr

Comment: @Darth а у меня в браузере ваш `console.log(localStorage.test) => null` всегда, и с начала и после перезагрузок.

Comment: @VostokSisters вместо того, чтобы гуглить пруфы, лучше взяли бы и попробовали. При перезагрузке страницы она, представьте себе, сначала закрывается, потом открывается снова, и beforeunload работает

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan https://otvet.imgsmail.ru/download/173260927_0806cc5cae9351f1b4263f679d11b803_800.jpg

Comment: @Darth так я попробовал. У меня почему-то в консоли не очищалась переменная в локал сторедж...

Comment: @Darth да, действительно, пример рабочий.

Comment: @Darth не знал, что перезагрузка - это и закрытие тоже)